# System.IO.File.Delete() not working

Tags: c#, asp.net

My code is like this

```
 public static void Deleter()
 {
     HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();
     HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
     HttpContext.Current.Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + "name" + ".pdf");
     HttpContext.Current.Response.TransmitFile("~/media/pdf/" + "name" + ".pdf");


     if (FileExists("/media/pdf/" + "name" + ".pdf"))
     {
         System.IO.File.Delete("D:/Projects/09-05-2013/httpdocs/media/pdf" + "name" + ".pdf");
     }
     HttpContext.Current.Response.End();

 }
```

after executing this entire code I still can see name.pdf in the folder.No error is thrown.can any one tell me whats going wrong?

Comment: Why is `"name"` in quotes everywhere? It looks like it wants to be a variable. Also, you are missing a `/` after `pdf` in the `Delete` call.

Comment: are you sure that `"/media/pdf/" + "name" + ".pdf"` and the file on the d drive are the same ?

Comment: Is it a typo or are you missing the final "/"? `System.IO.File.Delete("D:/Projects/09-05-2013/httpdocs/media/pdf/" + "name" + ".pdf");`

Comment: @Spaceman It was an error in my code.and that solved the issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your concatenated path would result in a wrong address, use [`Path.Combine`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.combine.aspx) to combine two paths. Current it would be:

```
D:/Projects/09-05-2013/httpdocs/media/pdfname.pdf
                                     ^^^^^^
                                    //Missing slash.
```

instead use:

```
System.IO.File.Delete(Path.Combine("D:/Projects/09-05-2013/httpdocs/media/pdf" 
                              , "name"+ ".pdf"));
```

Or if you want to use string concatenation then add a forward slash at the end of first string like:

```
System.IO.File.Delete("D:/Projects/09-05-2013/httpdocs/media/pdf/" + "name" + ".pdf");
```

Also consider using `Server.MapPath` instead of absolute path.

Answer (score 3):

The string concatenation

```
"D:/Projects/09-05-2013/httpdocs/media/pdf" + "name" + ".pdf"
```

yields

```
D:/Projects/09-05-2013/httpdocs/media/pdfname.pdf
```

which is the file you delete, and which is not the same as

```
D:/Projects/09-05-2013/httpdocs/media/pdf/name.pdf
```